# Unable to get element text using Selenium with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape Merriam-Webster's Medical Dictionary for medical terms using Python and Chrome as the Selenium webdriver. So far, this is what I have:

```
    from os import path
    from selenium import webdriver

    # Adding an ad-blocker to Chrome to speed up page load times
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_extension(path.abspath("ublock-origin.crx"))

    # Declaring the Selenium webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)

    # Fetching the "A" terms as a test set
    driver.get("https://www.merriam-webster.com/browse/medical/a")

    scraped_words = []  # The list that will hold each word
    page_num = 1
    while page_num < 55:  # There are 54 pages of "A" terms
        try:
            for i in range(4):  # There are 3 columns per page of words
                column = "/html/body/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/ul/li[" + str(i) + "]/a"
                number_of_words = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column))
                for j in range(number_of_words):
                    word = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]")
                    scraped_words.append(word)
            driver.find_element_by_class_name("fa-angle-right").click()  # Next page
            page_num += 1  # Increment page number to keep track of current page
        except:
            driver.close()

    # Write out words to a file
    with open("medical_terms.dict", "w") as text_file:
        for i in range(len(scraped_words)):
            text_file.write(str(scraped_words[i]))
            text_file.write("\n")

    driver.close()
```

The above code fetches all the items, as the output of `len(scraped_words)` is the number expected. However, since I did not specify that I wanted to fetch the text of the elements, I get element identifiers (I think?) instead of text. If I decide to use `word = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]").text` in order to specify that I want to get the text of the element, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mw_download.py", line 20, in <module>
    number_of_words = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 325, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 817, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mw_download.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 541, in close
    self.execute(Command.CLOSE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488774 (7e15618d1bf16df8bf0ecf2914ed1964a387ba0b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

What is strange to me here is that the only code I change between runs is on line 22 yet the error message points out line 20 instead.

Any help in deciphering what's going on here and what I can do to fix it would be much appreciated! :+)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create a `words` list accessing your elements texts, changing:

```
word = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]")
```

to:

```
word = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]")]
```

Because `.find_elements_by_xpath` will always return a list, accessing `.text` directly won't work.

Comment: Great explanation; thank you for helping me understand what was going wrong! :+)

Comment: So this definitely solved the above question, but I would appreciate a bit of help on these as well: 1) the last word of every column is recorded as a blank line and 2) trying to replace text using `word = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]")]` followed by `word = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', word)` results in the same error that is shown in the original post. Any ideas as to why either of these is happening and what I might try to fix these?

Comment: * `word = re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '', word)`

Comment: Oh, you are correct. You can bypass this blanks by adding a `if i` in the end of the comprehension: `word = [i.text for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]") if i]`

Comment: Actually **`if i.text`** =)

Comment: I figured out that the reason there was a missing word per column is because I was incorrectly indexing so I'm getting all the words now but am still getting blank entries between each column even with `if i.text` appended to the end of the list comprehension statement, for some reason.

Comment: hmm, that's weird, but I think I overcomplicated the solution, there is a better one. I'll edit my answer with it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't test the code since I'm on mobile, so I don't think editing it will be a good idea, but analysing your code, maybe just `word = driver.find_element_by_xpath(column + "[" + str(j) + "]").text`

Comment: The website is not responding well to my queries now, so I can't test it =/ I'd say this above should work. Also, note you can just delete empty lists in post-processing.

Comment: No, I don't think you over-complicated it! Your solution worked just fine. Actually, the "simpler" solution you suggested two comments ago is what I had tried before that hadn't worked, which is what prompted me to ask this question in the first place! :+) I will just delete those blank lines in post-processing, then.

Comment: One more thing: whenever I try to manipulate text after the list comprehension line, it keeps giving me the same error as in the original post for some reason. For example, if I add the following line of code: `print(word.replace("\'", ""))` between the list comprehension line and the line adding each word to `word_list`, I get the same error in the original post. This error points towards line 21 (the line defining `number_of_words`), which wasn't modified between runs. That's so strange! Any idea what's happening and why I can't post-process words in that list? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @paanvaannd `word` is a list, try operating your changes using `word[0]`

Comment: Thanks! I had noticed my mistake a couple hours ago and it's working for the most part now! I still can't seem to remove the blank lines for some reason but I'll figure it out eventually. Thanks for all the help, and I hope you have a great week! :+)

Comment: @paanvaannd remove the empty lists? try something like `newlist = [x for x in scraped_words if x != []]`

Comment: Got it to work now; I wasn't including that line where I should have been. Thanks for all your help, again! :+)